# Visual studio debugger not stepping into service layer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

i am facing very strange error . `Visual studio` suddenly stopped stepping into service layer
i tried every possible way to enter into service layer but debugger not entering into service layer only return response
i change development machine tried on different version of `Visual studio` but still the results are same
but the solution is stepping into and works properly on other team member system

i am using `WCF service` which is hosted on localsystem but on `https`

note: our system is binded with Active directory and to get the project we have to be in company domain so on different machine i login with same user may be there is some issue with user account but i am un aware of that
plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Try the below pointed things and see if it works

```
1.Close your solution -> close Visual Studio -> Reopen VS and open solutions
2. Update all the service references 
3. Clean and re-build your entire solution
4. Run your solution and attach the WCF service host
5. Put a break-point explicitly in the service method 
   where you want to break to [optional but worth trying]
6. Start debugging and see if it works fine
```

Comment: did this but results are same

Comment: In that case consider re-installing your visual studio once again.